# Delete Files in SharePoint List root folder

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I would like to delete all documents in the root folders of a SP List named `RecordsDocument`.

Below is my current script (currently deleting folders):

```
$web = Get-SPWeb "http://url.com"
$Libraries = $web.Lists | where {$_.BaseType -eq "DocumentLibrary"}
$RecordDocumentTotalCount = 0

foreach ($library in $Libraries) {

    if ($($library.Title) -eq "RecordsDocument")
    {
         Write-Output "Getting folders from $($library.Title)"
         $Folders = $library.Items | where {$_.FileSystemObjectType -eq "Folder"}
         foreach ($folder in $Folders) 
         {
            Write-Output "Deleting folder $($folder.Name)..."
            #$file.Delete()
        }
    }
}
```

However, in each folder, there is a `Document Set`, and in each `Document Set`, there are documents in it.

How can I remove the documents in the root folder instead of purging the entire folder?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Caml query to find files with ViewAttributes property.

[image]

[image]

[image]

http://www.codegrimoire.com/2013/08/scopes-in-caml-query.html

Use caml query in PowerShell, check [this thread](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaevans/2012/02/13/iterating-large-sharepoint-lists-with-powershell/).